# Subject-modifier-verb agreement

Tags: commas, verb-agreement, subjects, modifiers, compound-subjects

In the following sentence, is the verb 'have' appropriate? Is it not supposed to be 'has' ?

> The British council, in partnership with Microsoft philanthropies, have designed a course for young entrepreneurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular) Or [_The government is proposing_ or _The government are proposing_ ... – or are we allowed to choose ... ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497860/the-government-is-proposing-or-the-government-are-proposing-or-are-we) (closed as a duplicate)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem that arises with nouns such as *family*, *committee* and others. The council is an entity requiring singular verb, but is often seen as a collective followed by the verb in the plural. When folk think of the entity they use the singular (*our council is a statutory body*); when they think of members of the entity they use the plural (*the council are political pawns*).

Interestingly, even an authority like the Cambridge dictionary is not prescriptive, and indeed offers examples of both usage:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/council)
>
> council
> noun [ C, + **sing/pl verb**]
>
> the group of people elected to govern a particular area, town, or city, and organize services for it:
>
> *The town/city council **is/are** responsible for keeping the streets clean.
>
> The local council **has/have** decided not to allocate funds for the project.*